# Spatialite error: obsolete libspatialite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, ubuntu

I am learning to use QGIS with the QGIS training manual (from the QGIS website). One of the excercises is to load vector data from a database (ch 3.1.3 in case you have the manual). When I try to do so I get the following error:

> Unexpected error when working with:
> /home/(...)/exercise_data/epsg4326/landuse.sqlite
>
> obsolete libspatialite: connecting to this DB requires using v.4.0 (or any >subsequent)

Does anyone know what's wrong? I am using Ubuntu (latest version, had same issue before update). I also had the following error when opening QGIS:

> Couldn't load PyQGIS.
> Python support will be disabled.

I'm just mentioning this in case it is related, if not you can ignore it (will post seperate question if needed).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in error message you need to install `libspatialite` version 4 or higher. I use OpenSUSE and this package is called `libspatialite5` there. Here you are a couple of links to tutorials for installing spatialite on Ubuntu: [Installing Spatialite 4 on Ubuntu](http://wiki.fedarch.org:8090/display/FAIMS/Installing+Spatialite+4+on+Ubuntu), [Spatialite on Ubuntu](http://www.surfaces.co.il/spatialite-on-ubuntu/).